# Unable to proxy to a different port in Nginx using SSL

Tags: nginx, amazon-cloudfront, nginx-reverse-proxy, portforwarding

**Background**

I have an API running on port 8000 locally. To be able to access this via hostname, I did a bit of setup in AWS

- stream.mydomain.com -> S3 (website redirect to webstream.mydomain.com:8000)
- webstream.mydomain.com -> Public IP

**Target**

This works with HTTP, however in an effort to add SSL, I set my port forwarding to 443, ran nginx on my destination machine proxying it to localhost:8000, modifying AWS config as below

- stream.mydomain.com -> CloudFront endpoint (binding SSL cert, redirect http to https
- CloudFront endpoint -> S3 (website redirect to webstream.mydomain.com *without port number and enforcing https*)
- webstream.mydomain.com -> Public IP

**Problem**

Traffic flow worked just as it should, I was able to see the incoming connections in Nginx access logs, however my API running on port 8000 never received the request.

There was nothing in nginx error logs.

**Question**

Was this even a right setup to begin with?

I know Let's Encrypt or any download-able public certificate is a solution, but I want to know what's wrong with this setup.

**Troubleshooting**

- Swapped from local IP address to 127.0.0.1
- Ran curl on localhost and local IP address on port 8000 - both work fine
- `curl -v https://webstream.mydomain.com` - `* error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number`
- `nslookup webstream.mydomain.com` - resolved to my public IP address
- `openssl s_client -connect webstream.mydomain.com:443` - `408728AAF77F0000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:354:`
- `sudo tcpdump -i lo -n port 8000` - No activity when connected to `webstream.mydomain.com`

I have this API written in both Python (FastAPI) and Rust (Actix) but neither received the connection

**Nginx config**

***Nginx with SSL termination at the CloudFront level***

I setup a redirect in nginx, to get away from the mandatory args `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` when using SSL

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name webstream.mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name webstream.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

***OpenSSL Error Message***

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
408728AAF77F0000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:354:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 325 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

***Curl Error***

```
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (5454) (IN), , Unknown (72):
* error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
```